# Bootstraptour page is breaking UI in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have a page that implemented using bootstraptour (a product tour page). It's working fine in large screens, like desktops and laptops.

But when I open that page in mobile device the entire UI is breaking, so I have found that there is no viewport in header.

So i have added following tag in header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and after that UI is much better but still breaking a lot. So is there anything that I need to add?

This is my page head links:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/Chart.js"></script> 
<!-- JavaScript --> 
<script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/bootstrap-tour.js"></script> 
<script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/demo.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Hachi| Product Tour</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/css_new/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/css_new/tour_app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Google Web Font -->
    <link href="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/css_new/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/css_new/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//dujl9qf395ztu.cloudfront.net/js_new/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: your including jquery twice...Also why are you including JS *before* the `<head>`?

Comment: is that a wrong step?

Comment: Not sure if that will fix your problem, but certainly you should include JS either in the `<head>` or before the closing `</body>` tag, and only include jquery once, before any other JS files that might need it.

Comment: i done the changes you have mentioned and trying to run now

Comment: still it showing ui break...is there any meta tag do i need to add?